# Making Sense of this Error Message

Tags: data-mining, pandas, data-cleaning, k-nn, error-handling

I am using a book and a video to learn how to use KNN method to classify movies according to their genres.This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

r_cols = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating']

ratings = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/dell/Downloads/DataScience/DataScience-Python3/ml-100k/u.data', sep='\t', engine='python', names=r_cols, usecols=range(3))                         # The file is u.data from MovieLens
print(ratings.head())   


movieProperties = ratings.groupby('movie_id').agg({'rating': [np.size, np.mean]})
print(movieProperties.head())


movieNumRatings = pd.DataFrame(movieProperties['rating']['size'])
movieNormalizedNumRatings = movieNumRatings.apply(lambda x: (x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x)))
print(movieNormalizedNumRatings.head())


movieDict = {}
with open('C:/Users/dell/Downloads/DataScience/DataScience-Python3/ml-100k/u.item') as f:                       # The file is u.item from MovieLens
    temp = ''
    for line in f:
        fields = line.rstrip('\n').split('|')
        movieID = int(fields[0])
        name = fields[1]
        genres = fields[5:25]
        genres = map(int, genres)
        movieDict[movieID] = (name, genres, 
movieNormalizedNumRatings.loc[movieID].get('size'),           movieProperties.loc[movieID].rating.get('mean'))

print(movieDict[1])

from scipy import spatial
def ComputeDistance(a, b):
    genresA = a[1]
    genresB = b[1]
    genreDistance = spatial.distance.cosine(genresA, genresB)
    popularityA = a[2]
    popularityB = b[2]
    popularityDistance = abs(popularityA - popularityB)
    return genreDistance + popularityDistance        # Everything seems fine up to this point. But the problem seems to be the next line of code.

print(ComputeDistance(movieDict[2], movieDict[4]))
```

**Note**: This code can be found here: https://hendra-herviawan.github.io/Movie-Recommendation-based-on-KNN-K-Nearest-Neighbors.html

**Note**: This code can also be found on pg 245-250, chp7, Hands-On Data Science and Python Machine Learning by Frank Kane. I have an e-copy and I can send it on request.

**Note**: I don't know how to share the csv files here. I will appreciate it if somebody can tell me how I can do that here.

Comment: What are the types of ``movieDict[2][1]`` and ``movieDict[4][1]`` (it is the objets which are passed to ``spatial.distance.cosine``)?

Comment: Please avoid giving code as an image, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/891919

Comment: The `return genreDistance([...])` line is strange. `genreDistance` is a double precision float, it cannot be called as a function.
Not sure what is the point of this instruction.

Comment: The `return` statement should be something like `return genreDistance + popularityDistance` or another combination of previously computed distances.

Comment: @Romain Reboulleau Please check out the link I provided to see things for yourself. I also tried what you recommended but I got an error message

Comment: What I see in the link is the exact statement I suggested: `return genreDistance + popularityDistance`

Comment: @ Romain Reboulleau Oh, you are right. I have fixed it. However, I still get error message. I don't know what else I am missing

Comment: Ok, now what's the error message and the line raising it?

Comment: @Romain Reboulleau It says the following: in cosine return correlation (u, v, w=w, centered=False). In correlation uv = np.average(u*v, wights=w). TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'map' and 'map'

Comment: It also highlights the lines for genreDistance and print(ComputeDistance...)

Comment: @MrProf please edit the question to include add the error, not only in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have bumped into what works. I am posting the correct code since somebody may need this someday:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

r_cols = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating']

ratings = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/dell/Downloads/DataScience/DataScience-Python3/ml-100k/u.data', sep='\t', engine='python', names=r_cols, usecols=range(3))  # please enter your file path here. The file is u.data

print(ratings.head())  


movieProperties = ratings.groupby('movie_id').agg({'rating': [np.size, np.mean]})

print(movieProperties.head())


movieNumRatings = pd.DataFrame(movieProperties['rating']['size'])

movieNormalizedNumRatings = movieNumRatings.apply(lambda x: (x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x)))

print(movieNormalizedNumRatings.head())


movieDict = {}

with open('C:/Users/dell/Downloads/DataScience/DataScience-Python3/ml-100k/u.item') as f:     # The file is u.item

    temp = ''

    for line in f:

        fields = line.rstrip('\n').split('|')

        movieID = int(fields[0])

        name = fields[1]

        genres = fields[5:25]

        genres = map(int, genres)

        movieDict[movieID] = (name, genres, movieNormalizedNumRatings.loc[movieID].get('size'), movieProperties.loc[movieID].rating.get('mean'))

print(movieDict[1])


from scipy import spatial

def ComputeDistance(a, b):

    genresA = np.array(list(a[1]))

    genresB = np.array(list(b[1]))

    genreDistance = spatial.distance.cosine(genresA, genresB)

    popularityA = np.array(a[2])

    popularityB = np.array(b[2])

    popularityDistance = abs(popularityA - popularityB)

    return genreDistance + popularityDistance  

print(ComputeDistance(movieDict[2], movieDict[4]))
```

I am using this opportunity to thank those who gave me one or two suggestions.